# how to set error message for C# application supporting application missing

Tags: c#

I am maintaining C# desktop application, where the application becomes unresponsive during setup if the supporting application (say, excel, audio driver) is disabled or not installed. I need to set an error message corresponding to the application that was not installed. what would be the modification I need to do and the corresponding code that need to be changed? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to SO....Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by "Setup" you mean first-time execution; this answer may not cover installer problems. If you're having a problem with an *installer*, please updates your tags accordingly.

In a nutshell, there's no code you can modify to make this work as described. You're receiving exceptions from .NET, and while .NET is open source and you could potentially modify in changes, you won't be able to guarantee that your modified assemblies appear on client machines, and thus the changes are useless.

You're better off trying to catch exceptions as they happen, report, and cleanly exit. The easiest way to do this is to make sure your `Main` function wraps most/all execution in a `try`-`catch`, and assume anything caught by this top-level `catch` is a critical error and results in immediate shutdown.

For debugging, note that you can always attach to the [`FirstChanceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception(v=vs.110).aspx), however this is rarely recommended as a reporting feature as it will catch a number of exceptions that don't actually kill your application.